# Set Gmail as protocol handler

Tags: gmail, google-chrome, mailto

Websites can ask permission to make themselves protocol handlers, which means that when you click on a link with a certain protocol, that link will be opened "using" that website.

How do I do this with Gmail for the `mailto` protocol?

I'm using Chrome, but I hope there is some setting in Gmail that I can toggle for this, so that I don't need to ask this for every browser I use.

I looked in the Chrome settings, and there is a way to manage protocol handlers, but not to add new ones. The option can be found under the privacy settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a gmail setting.

I know that in Firefox you can set it under options/applications. Just set the mailto link.

For IE I can set it via the Google toolbar.

I don't have chrome on this computer.

Answer (score 3):

in Windows 7...go to Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Default Programs...choose your email handler and make sure you go in and click box next to allow for Mail To: protocols for Google Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but maybe there is a add-on that lets you customize your protocol handlers, or look in the browser config. Have you checked the Labs section of the Gmail opitions? Maybe there's something there. In Firefox we can both configure via opitions and add-on based.